# Java employee program

Tags: java

I've been working on a program as a assignment for quiet some time now and I just can't seem to get it to work properly When I return my employee name it just appears as **employee.Employee@7f787395**. I do not know how to make it so if I set The first employee as one of the empTypes. So I was wondering if anyone could show me how to do or or Where I am going Wrong.

```
class employee {
private static int empCount;
private String empName;
private double empSalary;
private double empRate;
private double empHour;
private double empBase;
private static int empPieces;
private static int empType;

public employee(String name){
this.empName = name;
empCount++;
}

 public String getName(){   
 return this.empName;    
 }
```

The method `setEmployeePay( )` is overloaded to accommodate different payment methods based on empType:

```
public void setEmployeePay(double Salary){

empType = 2; 
Salary = 45350.00;
}
public void setEmployeePay(double rate, double hours){

empType =1;
rate = 22.50;
hours = 35.0;

}
 public void setEmployeePay(double base, int pieces){
base = 500.00;
pieces = 25;
empType =3;

}
```

A static field, empCount, keeps track of the number of instantiated employees and can be retrieved using the static method `getCount( )`

```
    public static int getCount(){
    int empCou = 1;
    empCou = empCou + 1;

    return empCou;
 }

 public static int getNumber(){
 Random random = new Random(); 
     int empnumber = 1000 + random.nextInt(9999);

 return empnumber;
 }
```

Here is where I'm suppose to get it to return a number between 1000 and 9999 but I can't seem to get it to do that

```
 public double calculatePay(){

     return empSalary;
 }
```

The method `calculatePay( )` will determine what the employee's weekly pay is, based on their payment type but I don't know what I'm going to do here

```
 }
```

and this is my main method

```
package employee;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lab3 {

public static void main(String[] args, int empCount) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    empCount = 0;


    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: " );
    String name =input.next();
    Employee e1= new Employee(name);
    System.out.printf( "Employee count is " + empCount+ "\n" );


    e1.setEmployeePay(253553);
    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    name =input.next();
    Employee e2= new Employee(name);
    System.out.println( "Employee count is " + empCount );


    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    name =input.next();
    Employee e3= new Employee(name);
    System.out.println( "Employee count is " + empCount );


    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    name =input.next();
    Employee e4= new Employee(name);
    System.out.println( "Employee count is " + empCount );


   System.out.println("Employee "+empnumber+ e1.getName()+" earned: " +"");
   System.out.println("Employee "+empnumber+ e2.getName()+" earned: " +"");
   System.out.println("Employee "+ empnumber+ e3.getName()+" earned: " +"");
   System.out.println("Employee " + empnumber +e4.getName()+" earned: " +"");




}
```

Comment: In your ``employee`` class you are using lower case, but in your main method you are using ``Employee`` with capital letter. So maybe you are using two different classes here. Please check this. In general, Java class names should always start with a capital letter. And pay attention to your file name then, it's should be equal to the class name (case sensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// just rename the class to Employee//

class Employee{

}

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding toString method in your Employee class like:

```
public String toString() {
    return "empName: " + empName ...;
}
```

Comment: See what OP says "it just appears as employee.Employee@7f787395" he is just printing employee object and in code he modified it.